# Converting date to a String

Tags: php, string, datetime

I've faced with converting Date to String by using `date()` function in php.

Simply, I just want to print this '17th of January 2012' by using format character.

```
print date("jS of F Y");
```

However, the output was 17th 2012f January 2012 and.. is there any way to escape 'o' string to get the output I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape the `o` with a backslash:

```
print date("jS \of F Y");
```

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/function.date.php):

> You can prevent a recognized character in the format string from being expanded by **escaping it with a preceding backslash**.

Answer (score 4):

Just put a backslash `\` before `o` like this:

```
print date("jS \of F Y");
```